# What is the "big-M" method? And are there two of them?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, logical-constraints, big-m

I’ve seen the "big-$M$ method" referred to in different ways. What is the "big-$M$ method" and why does it seem to mean two different things?

Comment: just a suggestion to improve the post, perhaps it would be better to include examples where they seems to mean different things?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

People do use the term "big-$M$ method" to mean two different things. In both cases, the name refers to the use of a large constant, often denoted $M$.

The first use of the term refers to a [method for finding an initial feasible solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method) for the simplex method. (Another common method for doing this is the two-phase method.)

Sometimes people also use the term "big-$M$ method" to refer to the use of big-$M$ parameters in logical constraints in (mixed-)integer programming problems. For example: if $x$ is a continuous variable and $y$ is a binary variable, then the constraint
$$x \le My$$
says that if $y=0$, then $x$ must equal 0, and if $y=1$, then the constraint places no restrictions on $x$. Note that in this case, it’s important not to choose a value of $M$ that is *too* large.

*Aside*: I highly recommend @prubin's excellent [blog post](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/07/perils-of-big-m.html) on big-$M$ in all its forms.

Comment: Most common might be dependent on background: As an OR researcher coming from a CS background, the MIP usage was the only one I ever saw. I only saw the LP meaning when I read Winston's book in preparation for teaching an OR optimization class.

Comment: I think Winston is the *only* person who refers giving a huge infeasibility penalty in the simplex method as the "big-M" method.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: Hillier and Lieberman do too. So does [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method).