# Big M Modelling

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, big-m

It is advised that in a big M constraint, M should be chosen as small as possible.

Is this recommendation a hard fact or heuristics?

Comment: The smaller your big M constant, the stronger/sharper is the MIP model's relaxation. See [this question and its answers](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-is-it-important-to-choose-big-m-carefully-and-what-are-the-consequences-of-d) for more details.